# Javascript e-mail validation of specific domains

Tags: javascript

I can’t figure out what is missing so that when e-mail is valid it will skip the last invalid message and move to next item on form for validation:

```
enter code here 
    if (document.form1.email.value.length > 0) {

    var tst = document.form1.email.value;
    var okd = ['bankofamerica.com','baml.com','magner.com','ml.com','ust.com','ustrust.com']
    for (var i = 0; i < okd.length; i++) { okd[i] == okd[i].toLowerCase() }

    var emailRE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/
    var aLst = emailRE.exec(tst)
    if (!aLst) {
        alert(tst + ' is not a valid e-mail')
    } else {
        var sLst = aLst[1].toLowerCase()
        for (var i = 0; i < okd.length; i++) {
            if (sLst == okd[i]) {
                //    alert(aLst[1] + ' is allowed');-->

           }
       }

            if (i == okd.length) alert(aLst[1] + ' is not allowed.  Please enter an email address with an authorized domain.')

            document.form1.email.select();
            return false;


    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend placing this code into a function, maybe named `ValidateEmail()`.

In your loop: if you've determined the email is valid, `return true;`.  This will prevent further execution.  If that domain doesn't match, have it continue looping to check the others.

If the loop completes without returning `true`, you'll know it didn't match anything so `return false;` at the very end.

**EDIT:** Use try/catch instead:

```
if (document.form1.email.value.length > 0) {

    var tst = document.form1.email.value;
    var okd = ['bankofamerica.com','baml.com','magner.com','ml.com','ust.com','ustrust.com']
    for (var i = 0; i < okd.length; i++) { okd[i] == okd[i].toLowerCase() }

    try {
        var emailRE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/
        var aLst = emailRE.exec(tst)

        if (!aLst)
            throw (tst + ' is not a valid e-mail');

        // isValidDomain will be changed to 'true' only if it matches an item in the array
        var isValidDomain = false;

        var sLst = aLst[1].toLowerCase()
        for (var i = 0; i < okd.length; i++) {
            if (sLst == okd[i]) {
                isValidDomain = true;
                // We break here because a match has been found - no need to compare against the other domain names.
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isValidDomain)
            throw (aLst[1] + ' is not allowed.  Please enter an email address with an authorized domain.');

        // If execution reaches here, you know it passed both tests!
        return true;

    }
    catch(err) {

        // This code block runs whenever an error occurs

        alert(err);
        document.form1.email.select();
        return false;
    }
}
```

`throw` basically acts like a `goto` command.  It will jump directly to the `catch(err)` portion of the code.

More info about try, catch, and throw:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_throw.asp

Comment: Also, in your first `if` statement, you can `return false;` is the email definitely isn't valid.  This will prevent checking each domain.

Comment: Not working, apparently I don't know how to do it...

There has to be a GoTo command or something to let it jump the last if when already true...why is this so tough?

Comment: I don't need a loop, or a break, I just need it to go to next step and skip the last

Comment: I've got a much better/clearer solution for you.  Please see my revised answer for the code example.

Comment: Thank You!  Part was my fault - I think it is comparing the entire e-mail to the domain half past "@"...?

Comment: OK, that seems to work except that again the "Break" stops the entire process from continuing to the next form element which in this case is username.  I took break out originally because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Colin!

I had to remove the following 2 lines to avoid halting the code from running on to next validation field:

```
              isValidDomain = true;
                    // We break here because a match has been found - no need to compare against the other domain names. 
                    // break - exits code from running on down to next item on page
                }
            }

            if (!isValidDomain)
                throw (aLst[1] + ' is not allowed.  Please enter an email address with an authorized domain.');

            // If execution reaches here, you know it passed both tests! 
         //   return true; - was not needed, stops code from running on page

        }
        catch (err) {
```