# Jquery inArray return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Through this code I would like to understand if an email address contains the domain contained in an array, but the function always returns -1

```
var ele = jQuery('#email'); 
console.log( 'Email : ' + ele.val() ); 
var emailarr = ["gmail.com", "live.it", "email.it", "email.com", 
               "hotmail.it", "yahoo.it", "tiscali.it", "alice.it",
               "icloud.com", "outlook.com", "outlook.it", "inwind.it",
               "libero.it", "me.com", "mail.com", "virgilio.it", 
               "hotmail.com", "msn.com", "ymail.com","protonmail.com", 
               "fastwebnet.it" , "aruba.it"]; 
console.log( 'Index : ' + emailarr.indexOf(ele.val()) );
if (jQuery.inArray(ele.val(), emailarr) !== -1) { 
    ele.removeClass('error').addClass('normal'); 
} 
else { 
    jval2.errors = true; 
    ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('error'); 
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Because `'dasdas@gmail.co'` (etc) isn't in your array.

Comment: well "dasdas@gmail.com" is different than "gmail.com". You should only test the domain and not the entire email.

Comment: And indexOf same?

Comment: With this it work ele.val().split('@')[1], thanks =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript e-mail validation of specific domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197869/javascript-e-mail-validation-of-specific-domains)

Comment: I just need if email contains a specific domain not a regex for check if is an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/szrL16tv/2/)

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="email" value="dasdas@gmail.com">
```

JS Code

```
var ele =jQuery('#email');


        console.log( 'Email : ' + ele.val().split('@')[1] );

        var emailarr = ["gmail.com", "live.it", "email.it", "email.com", "hotmail.it", "yahoo.it", "tiscali.it", "alice.it", "icloud.com", "outlook.com", "outlook.it", "inwind.it", "libero.it", "me.com", "mail.com", "virgilio.it", "hotmail.com", "msn.com", "ymail.com", "protonmail.com", "fastwebnet.it" , "aruba.it"];
console.log( 'Index : ' + emailarr.indexOf(ele.val().split('@')[1]) );
                            if(jQuery.inArray(ele.val().split('@')[1], emailarr) !== -1)
                            {
                                ele.removeClass('error').addClass('normal');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                jval2.errors = true;
                                ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('error');
                            }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks =)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023336/jquery-inarray-return-false/54023549?noredirect=1#comment94883039_54023336

Comment: yours welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because you're looking for something (an e-mail address) in an array which doesn't contain it (your array contains only domains).

So in actual fact it seems you want to check not the full e-mail but just the domain part.

So you can do:

```
//better to rename emailarr to domains, since that's what it is
if (domains.filter(dmn => new RegExp('@'+dmn.replace(/(?=\.)/g, '\\')+'$').test(ele.val())).length) {
    //OK...
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdcps0y8/2/).

If you find the RegExp gymnastics a bit unreadable you can instead do:

```
let email_domain = ele.val().split('@')[1];
if (domains.filter(dmn => dmn == email_domain).length) {
    //OK...
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gukLf29b/)

Comment: Thanks, but i have solved with ele.val().split('@')[1]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking against the entire email, not just the domain. Thus, adding the following check should fix the bug;

```
if (jQuery.inArray(ele.val().substring(ele.val().indexOf('@') + 1), emailarr) !== -1) { 
        ele.removeClass('error').addClass('normal'); 
} 
else { 
    jval2.errors = true; 
    ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('error'); 
}
```